# Concentration of emperical conditional probability

Tags: pr.probability, sequences-and-series, markov-chains, measure-concentration

Assume sequence $(X_1,X_2, X_3, \ldots)$ is a first-order Markov sequence of real random variables where $X_i \in \mathcal{X}$ for some alphabet $\mathcal{X}$ of finite size $k$. Define emperical conditional probability $p_{X_i| X_{i-1}}(x_{i}|x_{i-1})$ after $n$ samples as
$$\hat{p}_{X_{i}|X_{i-1}}(x_{i}|x_{i-1}) = \frac{\sum_{i=2}^{n}\mathbb{I}\{X_{i-1} = x_{i-1} ,  X_i = x_i\} }{\sum_{i=2}^{n}\mathbb{I}\{X_{i-1} = x_{i-1}\}}.$$
for some $\{x_{i-1},x_i\} \in \mathcal{X}$ and $i >1$ and indicattor function $\mathbb{I}\{\cdot\}$, and the true probability as $p_{X_{i}|X_{i-1}}(x_{i}|x_{i-1})$.

Is there any Hoeffding-type inequality to show concentration rate of $\hat{p}_{X_i |X_{i-1}}(x_i|x_{i-1})$ around $p_{X_{i}|X_{i-1}}(x_i|x_{i-1})$, given that the underlying Markov process is irreducible.

**Possible start:** For the joint probability, $p_{X_{i},X_{i-1}}(x_i,x_{i-1})$, we can define $Y_i = (X_{i-1},X_i)$ for $i > 1$. Then, since $Y_2, Y_3, \ldots$ is Markov, we may use Theorem 2 of [Glynn'02](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjR3fitmNDYAhXC_iwKHaI9AfkQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.stanford.edu%2F~glynn%2Fpapers%2F2002%2FGOrmoneit02.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0PbgpKi4yOyp0ws-ftgzUC) for $Y$.

Comment: You need some assumptions, such as irreducibility. Assuming that, you converge exponentially in $n$. This follows e.g. from the Large Deviations for the empirical measure and the pair empirical measure.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention the irreduciblity. Pair empirical measure is more concerned with joint probability of $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$ (I am  not sure though), for which we can directly use Glynn'02. My question is how to extend it for the conditional probability?

Comment: both numerator and denominator concentrate....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer is the minimum convergence rate of the nominator and the denominator, to their respective true probabilities.

If you consider $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ where $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ with some convergence rates $f_1(n)$ and $f_2(n)$,then for sufficiently large $n$ (at which $|b_n - b|\leq \epsilon$), $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to \frac{a}{b}$ at rate $f_1(n) + f_2(n)$.